# infinite loop marquee with css probleem

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

Hi ı am trying to make a infinite loop marquee with css. I mean ı want when 1 box go outside new box should come from left side the boxes always should be on the screen and fluent.

I tried this code but it is not working like ı want the 10 box is going then loop suddenly rewinds does not progress fluently.

```
<div class="marquee">
    <div class="slide">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

(in official code there is 20 box ı wrote just 1 for the example)

```
.marquee{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;

}
.slide{
    white-space: nowrap;
    will-change: transform;
    animation: marquee 4s 
    linear infinite;
    display: flex;


}
@keyframes marquee {
    from{transform:translateX(-10%);}
    to{transform:translateX(+10%) ;}
}
.box{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
   
 
}
```

Anyone know how ı will fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you are looking for. You need to add `overflow: hidden` on your `.slide` class to prevent the animation from exceeding the size of the slide and the boxes do not go further out. I added it on the class and also increased the `translateX` to have a smoother animation. Have a look on that. Hope it helps :)

```css
.marquee{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;

}
.slide{
    white-space: nowrap;
    will-change: transform;
    animation: marquee 4s 
    linear infinite;
    display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes marquee {
    from{transform:translateX(-100%);}
    to{transform:translateX(100%) ;}
}
.box{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
   
 
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```